# Django Rest Framework save multiple serializers in a celery task

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery

Am using Django rest framework, Celery, and RabbitMQ for my aplication. I have a task that does some data processing and saves the results as objects in my Django application. The task has two different results that need to be saved, so two model serializers are needed. The problem is that when the task is performed only one of the models is being saved. I tried the method while it was not a celery task and it worked perfectly, and i don't know what changes when it is run as a task that it won't work any more.

this is the code runned in the task:

```
def createMBGSimulations(petition_id):
    ...
    Data process
    ...

    prices = s_Q.tolist()
    lists_ci = cis.tolist()

    serializer = serializers.PriceSerializer(data={})
    serializer_ci = serializers.ConfidenceIntervalSerializer(data={})
    if serializer.is_valid():
        petition = models.Petition.objects.get(pk=petition_id)
        serializer.save(prices=prices, petition=petition)
        if serializer_ci.is_valid():
            serializer_ci.save(ci=lists_ci, petition=petition)
            petition.clean()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Which one is saved? Did the `is_valid` calls both return `True`?

Comment: @micsucmed There are limitations while using serializer in celery task. see this [blog](https://www.oddbird.net/2017/03/20/serializing-things/)

Comment: @bdbd The prices one is saved no matter the order, and yes both return true. The weird thing is that it works perfectly when its not performed as a celery task.

Comment: @Madmax thank you for the input, I see the limitations now, I condensed both things in a single model so only a serializer is used and the limitations mentioned on the blog are met. It works as a celery task as it was intended now.